# Simple painting

Tags: java, awt

I have an seemingly very simple task at hand. I have a grid (500x500 right now) I want to visualize as it is populated and I want to write a class in Java that makes this easy for me to do. I'm thinking something along the line of:

```
public class Screen {
  ...

  public void plot(x,y) {
    // change the color of pixel x,y to black
  }

  public void clear() {
    // fill the screen with white
  }
}
```

I have been looking around and quickly found Canvas in awt, however from what I have been able to figure out so far, this widget will only allow me to draw on to it by overriding its paint method. This is far from optimal in my case as this will require me to draw the entire grid every time I wish to do just plot one single pixel.

Is there any way to get canvas to just draw a single pixel rather than the entire canvas? Or some other way to accomplish what I look for here?

I would prefer to avoid having to use any external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the paint method to display the entire grid.

However, what you can do is create a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) that flips the one pixel, and draw that entire image to the component in the paint method, using [Graphics.drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to override `paint()` and render the entire grid every time paint() is called. That's how graphical components work - the windows system/OS may request to repaint the component at any time (eg. when the window is re-shown/resized/moved)